# Подключится к MDB(MS Access) из PHP

Tags: php, pdo, access, odbc, mdb

Как открыть файл базы MDB и выполнить запрос из под PHP ???
Люди добрые подскажите какие пакеты установить и как настроить на Debian
Поиск информации мне не дал...
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю - это MS Access.
Согласно документации, доступ к ним осуществляется через ODBC. (http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.databases.php)

Доступ по ODBC отлично работает через PDO (http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

В случае Debian вам надо будет сначала установить и настроить unixODBC (http://www.unixodbc.org/)

Самая сложная часть во всей этой истории - грамотно настроить datasource для MS Access в самом unixODBC, но тут уж, извините, ищите сами, ибо я не готов в здравом рассудке соваться в этот ад.

PS Когда найдете решение, не поленитесь написать его в качестве ответа - наверняка кому-нибудь поможет в будущем